# WinApi - How To Prevent A Window From Opening

Tags: windows, winapi, focus

Can I forbid new windows to open on Windows ? I just want to prevent that another window steals my focus not even for a split second.

Is that possible ? And if yes how ?

```
// not sure if I can correct 1 letter mistakes on Stackoverfl0w
```

Comment: The 2nd worst thing you can do is trying to steal the foreground.  Stealing it back is the 1st worst thing you can do.  Nothing that pretty about a user helplessly staring at two windows flickering back and forth.

Comment: You got it all wrong! The worst thing happened to me today ... and sadly not for the first time. My AntiVir did damage to me with no "classic" malware involved. Now I consider this AV as malware!!!

Comment: @n4pgamer and how does that factor in with this question? Did your AV popup a window and as you were typing, it stole focus and your keystrokes or input activated some default AV action? If so, your AV program is poorly designed and you should file a bug report. Not seek to break Windows.

Comment: Most AV is indeed shrink-wrapped malware.  You solve it using the same technique your user will apply to your product.  You uninstall it.

Comment: If your app already has focus, another app **CANNOT** steal the focus without permission. Windows actually goes to great lengths to prevent focus stealing. See the documentation for [`SetForegroundWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx) for details: "An application cannot force a window to the foreground while the user is working with another window. Instead, Windows flashes the taskbar button of the window to notify the user."

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't such a thing (modulo the "secure desktop" scenarios) and it's a *good* thing too. Why? Because there **SHOULDN'T** be. Such a program, if coded, wouldn't even let me click on my taskbar...

Imagine, for a second, that such a feature was available. Now imagine two applications both thought they were so important that they should have the focus **all the time**. They would both say "I'm super important. Don't let anyone steal my focus." And then... what?

This is just bad design. Design your program sensibly and realize that it's very very **VERY** unlikely that it is so important and so amazing that users won't want to switch to anything else.

And keep one simple fact in mind: my computer belongs to **me**, not you, and if **I** want to open a new window, who are you to tell me I can't?

Comment: It will not be a classic desktop app. And design like this is actually not that uncommon. I did some sort of that for a production application where I needed to disable most of Windows functionality.

Comment: Whether it's a desktop app or not is not relevant. You are seeking to solve a problem the wrong way. The right approach isn't to prevent the stealing of focus. The right approach is to make losing focus **not matter**.

Comment: In this case losing focus is not acceptable. And isn't stackoverflow there for the purpose to help solve problems instead of saying "just don't do it" ?

Comment: @n4pgamer if your problem is how to shoot yourself in the foot, our purpose isn't to paint a target and hand you a loaded gun. Our purpose is to ask: “why would you want to do something that stupid?”

Comment: Are we now going to metaphor us to sleep ? Your "metaphor" isn't good. I was already shot in the foot. I'm trying to avoid that from happening again! And I feel more like you're trying to tell the Wright brothers "Don't try to fly because people will die!" Please help me answer my question!

Comment: @n4pgamer sorry you were shot in the foot. I'd like to help, but I can't, because you aren't helping me help you. I need to know the **actual** problem you are having, not the "solution" that you devised.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with WM_ACTIVATE, once you receive WA_INACTIVE set your window back to foreground. Maybe you can try the same trick with WM_KILLFOCUS, or some other functions. You can use Spy++ to investigate messages that are causing you window to loose focus.

I can imaging such "feature" would be of use in kiosk mode apps on embeded systems, or for some kind of security oriented aplications. Maybe you can tell more what your app is actually trying to do?

Comment: I don't see any use for such a "feature", not even in kiosk mode. If a user wants to click away from an application, they can click away from an application.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll try it. But there might be the problem with the split second I lose focus in.

Comment: @n4pgamer can you tell us what **ACTUAL** problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @NikBougalis I did tell that: I don't want my app to lose focus. The question is not that complicated and I can't go into detail what my program is doing.

Comment: @NikBougalis you mean for example in ATM it would be ok for you to run minesweeper?

Comment: @marcin_j Nice try. But not allowing a focus switch or blocking window creation is the wrong approach for an ATM. You want to limit process creation - once a process is to the point of making `CreateWindow` calls your imaginary ATM is already compromised.

Comment: @NikBougalis That was only an example, just to show You that you never know what problem you will have to solve. For example what about if I would like to write Toddler app, its a kind of game that your child (1 or 2 y.old) is not supposed to close, minimize or switch to other window/app. Only way to minimize it is to click on four corners of the screen.

Comment: @marcin_j Right - I don't know what the problem is. And that's why I cannot answer this question - only provide suggestions based on what little "hints" I have about the problem based on the OPs "solution." The OP must tell us what **actual** problem he's trying to solve before we can help him.